# Converting JSONObject to a string

Tags: android

I have this JSON data that I want to get from Android

```
{"success":1,"message":"Product successfully created."}
```

The full code is here:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("android");
$fname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from info  ");
if($sql)
{
    $response["success"] = 1
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    $data[]=$response;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    $output[]=$row;
json_encode($output);
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

What exactly I want to do is get response whether successfull of failed the rest works eg retrieving data from the database.

I tried this code:

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(sb.toString())
```

then

```
JSONObject objdata=obj.getJSONObject('success');
```

but got errors like "type mismatch" and "cannot be converted"

Comment: ...and please refer to the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the editing area, and the preview of your question that's shown below it as you write it. I've fixed it for you on this occasion, but this is your third question, you should have the hang of this by now.

Comment: `success` is not a JSONObject. it's a `int`. Try `obj.getInt("success")`

Comment: okay am checking this out

Comment: 07-12 09:07:55.555: W/System.err(847): org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":1} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: First create a `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`. Like you write above. Then call the `getInt()` method for that object. You should learn the JSON structure first.

Comment: JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
     int result=object.getInt("success"); did the majic thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shaiful said, success is not an object.

Either, use obj.getInt("success") to fetch it, or change your return to something a little more like this;

```
{
   "success":{
      "id":1,
      "message":"Product successfully created."
   }
}
```

If you would simply program more object-orientated in your PHP instead of converting arrays, this would go more automatically, since json_encode(); will create a proper json string for you also if you give it an object.

edit: You should **really** look up types (objects, arrays, ints, strings...) in combination with JSON and its syntax. Looking at your comments, you do not get a whole lot of it.

For the above JSON string in Android, create an object Success with an `Integer id` and a `String message`.

Then use the `Gson` library to extract it like this automatically:

```
Success mSuccess = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Success.class);
```

Comment: JSONObject reply=new JSONObject(data);       int  result=reply.getInt("success");       String message=reply.getString("message"); is still not working

Comment: i have the gson package from google but how to use it i dont know

Comment: I wrote out exactly how to use it in my post. There are thousands of gson parsing tutorials and your question involves pretty much the most simple case you can imagine. Good luck.

Comment: finally this did the majic **JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
     int result=object.getInt("success");**

Comment: i didnt use the library but this JSONObject object=new JSONObject(data);
     int result=object.getInt("success"); and the **php $testArr['success'] = 12; 
      print json_encode($testArr); i love stackoverflow**